# Ant unsupported error wont go away

Tags: java, ant

I am getting this error and tried almost everything I could think of.

I even reinstalled Ubuntu, downloaded jdk 5 from Oracle and then installed `maven2` and `ant 1.8` but all in vain.

I wrote a helloworld 'build.xml`and ran`ant` on it, but I still get the error below.

Just wondering if there is a hidden jar file that is not complied with the right version of compiler.

> BUILD FAILED java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version
>   number in .class file     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
>   Method)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
>     at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:300)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)     at
>   javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:88)    at
>   javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findJarServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:278)
>     at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:185)     at
>   javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.util.JAXPUtils.newParserFactory(JAXPUtils.java:120)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.util.JAXPUtils.getNSParserFactory(JAXPUtils.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.util.JAXPUtils.getNamespaceXMLReader(JAXPUtils.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:273)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:82)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:793)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Answer (score 0):

> rg.apache.tools.ant.util.JAXPUtils.newParserFactory(JAXPUtils.java:120)
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.util.JAXPUtils.getNSParserFactory(JAXPUtils.java:104)
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.util.JAXPUtils.getNamespaceXMLReader(JAXPUtils.java:172)
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:273)
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:178)
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:82)
>   at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:793) at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217) at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280) at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

It seems you have wrong version of apache jars in classpath which are not compiled for the jdk runtime you have on machine.

Comment: Thanks Nambari, but where is it picking these files from? I removed everything from .m2 directory and also from /usr/share/maven-repo.

Comment: Check classpath entries in environment variables and build.xml.